# How to get selection in DropDownList control in parent control Page_Load method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am relatively new to asp.net.

I have parent custom user control and child custom user control.
[image]

As you can see above child control has DropDownList control.

When selection changed in DropDownList control postback accrued and  `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method of the parent control is fired,

at this stage(in Page_Load method of the parent control) I need to get the selected value in DropDownList.

Any idea how can I get the selected value in DropDownList in Page_Load method of the parent control?

Comment: The better approach is to use events. If your page need to handle the event that the user selects an item in the DropDownList the UserControl should raise a custom event that the page can handle. On that way your UserControl remains reusable and is not hardwired with your page. The code is also more readable and less error-prone. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to expose either the control on your child control, or an accessor to the value of the same control. For example, in your code behind for the child control you could have a property like

```
public TextBox MyTextBoxControl 
{ 
    get { return MyLocalTextBoxControl; }
}
```

And then access it on the Page_Load of the main control like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var textValue = MyChildControl.MyTextBoxControl.Text;
    ...
}
```

Of course, you will need to decide if it makes better sense from a reusability standpoint whether to expose just the text portion of the control (or whatever property you need at the parent level) or access to the whole control.

For reference, you would expose access only to the text portion of the sub-sub control as follows.

```
public string MyTextBoxControlText 
{ 
    get { return MyLocalTextBoxControl.Text; }
    set { MyLocalTextBoxControl.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: It's the other way around, the UserControl wants to communicate with the page. The best way is called [event driven communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)